# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string but got:object. Check the render method of 'NavigatorIOS'

Tags: react-native

I am currently building my first react-native application, which is a simple clone of IMDB. I am using **NavigatorIOS** to manage state transaction and build my application as modular as possible.

The error occurs when I try to go to my **Movie** Component from my **Library** Component. The Library lists all the movies the user has stored and the Movie component takes simple takes an object and displays the information of the movie passed.

The peculiar thing is that I reuse my **Movie** Component from my **Search** Component and I am unable to reproduce the exception.

**Library Component:**

```js
var React = require('react-native');
var Separator = require('../Helpers/Separator');
var Movie = require('../Movie');

var {
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableHighlight,
  ActivityIndicatorIOS
} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  rowContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10
  },
  name: {
    color: '#48BBEC',
    fontSize: 18,
    paddingBottom: 5
  },
  year: {
    color: '#48BBEC',
    fontSize: 14,
    paddingBottom: 5
  },
  description: {
    fontSize: 14,
    paddingBottom: 5
  }
});

class Library extends React.Component{
  selectFilm(selectedMovie){
    this.props.navigator.push({
      title: selectedMovie.Title,
      component: Movie,
      passProps: { movie: selectedMovie, canSave: false, isAuthenticated: true }
   });
  }
  render(){
    var movies = this.props.movies;
    var list = movies.map((item, index) => {
      return(
        <View key={index}>
          <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
          <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={this.selectFilm.bind(this, movies[index])}
            underlayColor='transparent'>
            <Text style={styles.name}>{movies[index].title}</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
          <Text stlye={styles.year}>{movies[index].year}</Text>
          </View>
          <Separator />
        </View>
      )
    });
    return(
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        {list}
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
};

Library.propTypes = {
  movies: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

module.exports = Library;
```

**Movie Component:**

```js
var React = require('react-native');
var Badge = require('./Badge.js');
var Library = require('./User/Library.js');
var Separator = require('./Helpers/Separator');
var api = require('../Utils/api');

var {
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableHighlight,
  AsyncStorage
} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: 'white',
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
  rowContainer: {
    padding: 10
  },
  rowTitle: {
    color: '#48BBEC',
    fontSize: 16
  },
  rowContent: {
    fontSize: 19
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: '#111',
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
  button: {
    height: 45,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: '#758BF4',
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 8,
    marginBottom: 0,
    marginTop: 10,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
});

class Movie extends React.Component{
  componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("token").then((value) => {
        this.setState({"token": value});
    }).done();
  }
  getRowTitle(title){
    return title[0] ? title[0].toUpperCase() + title.slice(1): title;
  }
  getTitle(item){
    return item[0] ? item[0].toUpperCase() + item.slice(1) : item;
  }
  handleSubmit(){
    api.addMovie(this.state.token, this.props.movie)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            if (res === 'Film already exists') {
              alert('Film already exists');
            } else {
              alert('SAVED');
            }
        });
  }
  handleDelete(){
    api.deleteMovie(this.props.movie.imdbID)
      .then((res) => {
        this.props.navigator.pop();
      });
  }
  render(){
    var showSave;
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      showSave = (
        this.props.canSave ? <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} underlayColor="#48BBEC"><Text style={styles.buttonText}> SAVE </Text></TouchableHighlight> :
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this.handleDelete.bind(this)} underlayColor="#48BBEC"><Text style={styles.buttonText}>DELETE </Text></TouchableHighlight>
      );
    }
    var movie = this.props.movie;
    var topicArr = ['director', 'year', 'rated', 'plot', 'country', 'awards', 'imdbRating'];
    var list = topicArr.map((item, index) => {
      if (!movie[item]) {
        item = this.getTitle(item);
      }
      return (
        <View key={index}>
          <View style={styles.rowContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.rowTitle}>{this.getRowTitle(item)}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.rowContent}> {movie[item]} </Text>
          </View>
          <Separator />
        </View>
      )
    });
    return(
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <Badge movie={this.props.movie} />
        {list}
        {showSave}
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
};

Movie.propTypes = {
  movie: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

module.exports = Movie;
```

**Search Component:**

```js
var React = require('react-native');
var Movie = require('./Movie');
var api = require('../Utils/api');

var {
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableHighlight,
  StyleSheet,
  ActivityIndicatorIOS,
  AsyncStorage
} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // Styles
});

class Search extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: '',
      isLoading: false,
      token: ''
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("token").then((value) => {
        this.setState({"token": value});
    }).done();
  }
  handleChange(event){
    this.setState({
      title: event.nativeEvent.text
    });
  }
  handleSubmit(){
    var isAuthenticated = this.state.token !== null ? true : false;
    this.setState({
      isLoading: true
    });
    api.findMovie(this.state.title)
       .then((res) => {
         if (!res.Response) {
           this.setState({
             error: 'Movie not found',
             isLoading: false
           });
         } else {
           this.props.navigator.push({
               title: res.Title,
               component: Movie,
               passProps: {movie: res, canSave: true, isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated}
           });
           this.setState({
             isLoading: false,
             error: false,
             title: ''
           })
         }
       });
  }
  render(){
    var showErr = (
      this.state.error ? <Text>{this.state.error}</Text> : <View></View>
    );
    return(
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Search for a movie</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.searchInput}
          value={this.state.title}
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
        <TouchableHighlight
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
          underlayColor="white">
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}> SEARCH </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <ActivityIndicatorIOS
          animating={this.state.isLoading}
          color= "#111"
          size="large">
        </ActivityIndicatorIOS>
        {showErr}
      </View>
    )
  }
};

module.exports = Search;
```

Here is the application flow of my app:

[image: Application Flow]
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: since it doesn't error when coming from search, I think it would be helpful seeing that component too. in general, I suggest replacing the dynamic bits with hard coded bits do you can isolate the issue. one of the props being passed to NavigatotIOS is actually an object rather than string

Comment: Thanks, I added the code for the Search component. I hardcoded all the props and it still giving me the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figure it out!

Silly mistake from my part.

The solution was to remove the requirement for the **Library** Component from the **Movie** Component. Once I deleted that line the error was gone. It appears that you cannot require the same component you are transition from, if you do you're code will break.

Comment: so...it seems you had a nice Christmas :D

Answer (score 1):

I recevied this error because I registered the component twice.

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('HelloWorldApp', () => HelloWorldApp);
```